# pull down to change slides in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been seeing pull down to refresh in ionic. However, I wanted to implement something like changing slides  with a slide up or slide down effect using pull down gesture.

Is it possible to customize ion refresher that way or is it strictly meant to refresh?

Can I call a function that would set an active slide on inside of ion refresher  for on-refresh?

I am quite direction less about it as well. Can I please get some directions on customizing it that way?

I don't think I would like to use slide down gesture here as it would end up changing slide on slide down anywhere on the screen. I would like it happening from an icon on top of the screen instead, much like an ion refresher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ion-refresher` is just a directive which gives you `pull-down` effect, on its `on-refresh` you have to call your own function, so you can do anything inside in that function. As you are saying you want to set a any slide to active, you just do it this way

```
<ion-refresher
    pulling-text="Pull to change slide..."
    on-refresh="changeSlide()">
</ion-refresher>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.changeSlide = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(slide-number);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};
```

**NOTE**:

1. Dont forget to boradcast `scroll.refreshComplete` event after your
   action is done, because that gives signal to spinner of pull-down to
   stop.
2. My suggestion is not use this for purpose you mentioned, because as directive name
   (ion-refresher) depicts, this effect is meant to give user feel of
   refreshing data of page.If ionic named it this way, there must be a
   good reason for that.